# Message Controller and Mail Controller goes in portrait mode open via UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am facing too many issues when we present a `UIActivityViewController` and via that we open a `Message controller` and `Mail Controller` my app only supports Landscape mode. but this controller goes in portrait mode and after dismissal whole apps goes in portrait mode. can't we stop this kind behaviour of `UIActivityViewController`'s.

Note : This only happens in `iOS7` I have tried SubClassing `UIActivityViewController` and implementing this methods :

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight));
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```

But not helping the scenario. 
Any suggestions ?